# Add multiple gradient for chart area in chartjs line chart

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I would like to create a line chart with two gradients within the chart area, depending on the values. Specifically, I want one gradient to be applied to the chart area until a point where the values become NaN, and then a different gradient to be used from that point onwards. Here is the desired outcome [Desired chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5I6A.png). However, this is what I have achieved so far: [Current chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLsvn.png)

I have attempted to implement a gradient in one direction, which is working as expected. However, in my design, I require the gradient to have a top-to-bottom orientation, with a subdued gradient in the background for the deactivated section. This is the current status of my implementation, where the gradient is not meeting my design specifications.

```
useEffect(() => {
        var newChart = document.getElementById('areaChart').getContext('2d');
        newChart = new Chart(newChart, {
            type: 'line',
            data: { //chart area configuration
                labels: props.data && props.data.label.length > 0 ? props.data.label : [],
                datasets: [{
                    data: props.data && props.data.data.length > 0 ? props.data.data : [],

                    borderColor: [
                        Colors.deep_blue
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 2,
                    tension: 0.5,
                    fill: true,
                    pointRadius: 0,
                    pointHoverRadius: 8,
                    pointBorderWidth: 0,
                    pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
                    pointHoverBorderColor: Colors.deep_blue,
                    pointBorderColor: Colors.white,
                    pointBackgroundColor: '#e9ede7f0',
                    padding: 3,
                    segment: {
                        borderColor: ctx => skipped(ctx, `${Colors.deep_blue}`) || skipped(ctx, `${Colors.deep_blue}`),
                        borderDash: ctx => skipped(ctx, [4, 3]),
                        backgroundColor: function (context) {
                            const chart = context.chart;
                            const { ctx, chartArea } = chart;
                            const data = props.data && props.data.data.length > 0 ? props.data.data : [];
                            return _getGradient(ctx, chartArea, data);
                        }


                    },
                    spanGaps: true
                }]
            },
            options: { //chart  options
                hover: {
                    mode: 'index',
                    intersect: false,
                },
                scales: { // grid lines
                    x: {
                        beginAtZero: false,
                        border: {
                            display: false,
                        },
                        ticks: {
                            color: Colors.pale_blue,
                            display: false,
                            font: {
                                size: 12,
                                weight: 400,
                                family: 'Poppins-Regular'
                            }

                        },
                        grid: {
                            drawTicks: false,
                            drawBorder: false,
                            display: false
                        },
                    },
                    y: {
                        border: false,
                        beginAtZero: false,
                        ticks: {
                            display: false,
                            color: Colors.pale_blue,
                            padding: 10,
                            callback: function (value, index, ticks) {
                                return '₹' + value;
                            },
                            font: {
                                size: 14,
                                weight: 400,
                                family: 'Inter-Regular'
                            }

                        },
                        border: {
                            display: false,
                            dash: [8, 4],
                        },
                        grid: {
                            color: function (context) {
                                return Colors.pale_blue;

                            },
                            drawTicks: false,
                            drawBorder: false,
                        },
                    },
                },
                plugins: {
                    beforeDraw: function (chart) {
                        const ctx = chart.ctx;
                        const parsed = chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data.map((item) => item._parsed.y);

                        if (parsed.some(isNaN)) {
                            ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
                            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, chart.width, chart.height);
                        }
                    },
                    legend: { // remove legend
                        display: false,
                    },
                    corsair: { //  hover line
                        color: Colors.deep_blue,
                    },
                    tooltip: { //tooltip
                        enabled: false,
                        position: 'nearest',
                        external: externalTooltipHandler
                    },
                }
            }

        });
        return () => {
            newChart.destroy()
        }
    }, []);

const _getGradient = (ctx, chartArea, data) => {
        if (chartArea) {
            let width, height, gradient;
            const chartWidth = chartArea.right - chartArea.left;
            const chartHeight = chartArea.bottom - chartArea.top;
            // Set the gradient to red and blue vertically
            width = chartWidth;
            height = chartHeight;
            // gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(chartArea.right, 0, chartArea.left, 0);
            gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 250, 10, 0);
            gradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(42, 100, 217, 0.6)');
            gradient.addColorStop(0.5, 'rgba(42, 100, 217, .25)');
            gradient.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(42, 100, 217, 0)');

            return gradient;
        }
    };const _getGradient = (ctx, chartArea, data) => {
        if (chartArea) {
            let width, height, gradient;
            const chartWidth = chartArea.right - chartArea.left;
            const chartHeight = chartArea.bottom - chartArea.top;
            // Set the gradient to red and blue vertically
            width = chartWidth;
            height = chartHeight;
            // gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(chartArea.right, 0, chartArea.left, 0);
            gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 250, 10, 0);
            gradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(42, 100, 217, 0.6)');
            gradient.addColorStop(0.5, 'rgba(42, 100, 217, .25)');
            gradient.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(42, 100, 217, 0)');

            return gradient;
        }
    };
```

This is what i done so far. Thanks for the help

Comment: I have devised a solution by segregating the data into distinct datasets, one for active components and another for inactive components.